# Does there always exist some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $Q(c)>P(c)$?

Tags: polynomials

The following question came in my mind while solving a different problem:

> Two real valued polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ both have roots at $a,b$. WLOG, assume $a<b$. There exist $\delta _1, \delta_2$ such that, $$\forall x \in (a- \delta_1,a) \cup (b,b+ \delta_2) \quad P(x) > Q(x)$$ Does there always exist some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $Q(c)>P(c)$?

I'm not sure if this result above is true or not, but I tried with the intention of proving it correct. I approached it with contradiction, say $P(x) \geq Q(x)$ $\forall x \in (a,b)$ but I'm not able to get any contradiction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 I'm asking if the question in the quotation is true or not. Is the question in the quotation not clear by any chance?

Comment: Okay. I will say that the notation is, in fact, clear. However, you have only stated now that you are unsure whether the quotation is true or not. Would you be able to edit that into the question now?

Comment: I don't think it is true. Take $Q(x)=0$, one can easily find a polynomial with two roots and is also non-negative

Comment: @Koobe Can you give a specific example please. The property that $$\forall x \in (a- \delta_1,a) \cup (b,b+ \delta_2) \quad P(x) > Q(x)$$ has to be fulfilled as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(x)=(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$ and $Q(x)\equiv0$. Then $P(x)>Q(x)$ except for $x=a$ and $b$.